# Is it possible to have a global prettify-symbols-alist that other modes add to?

Tags: hooks, prettify-symbols-mode

Is it possible to have a global prettify-symbols-alist that other modes add to? 
A lot of major modes override prettify-symbols-alist instead of pushing into it. 
One solution I thought of is to push the global entries in a hook that runs after the buffer and its mode have initialized. I don't know of such a hook, unfortunately.

Comment: Why do you want to do something like that?

Comment: `after-change-major-mode-hook` is exactly the hook you are looking for.  Globalized modes also act there, so if you needed to do this *before* `global-prettify-symbols-mode` has enabled its buffer-local mode (which I think you probably do, although I haven't tested), then you would want to add to the hook *after* enabling that global mode (or otherwise manipulate the order).

Answer (score 2):

Modes usually inherit from each other. For example, `java-mode` inherits from `prog-mode` which inherits from `fundamental-mode`. Similarly, many modes inherit from `special-mode`. If you add a function to both `fundamental-mode-hook` and `special-mode-hook`, you should already cover many major modes.